# miscalculation in YouTube quota limits?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, quota

Though there are some questions on this context I am yet to understand the math of quota limits.

---

Google developer console states the following

Queries per day - 10,000
Queries per 100 seconds per user -  300,000
Queries per 100 seconds     3,000,000

So

1. A user can burn 300,000 / 100 = **3,000** units per second, which
   means 10K units can be exceeded after ~3.3 seconds. What if the client has 4 users? Can they burn all the units in a less than a second time period?
2. A client is allowed to burn 3M / 100 = 30,000 units per second which already exceeds daily 10K limit.

How can a client burn 3M units in a second if she only has 10K units per day.

Can someone help me understand all this magic, especially one from @YouTubeDev team?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its about Youtube api quota calculation and is not programming related.  It is also addressed to the YouTubeDev who do not respond here. OP should contact the @YouTubeDev team.

Comment: there are other several years old questions on this context , and they are still on the platform

Answer (score 0):

they reduced the daily quota limit from ~400.000 to 10.000 on the 5th March 2020. It was 1.000.000 a few months ago and 10.000.000 a few years ago.

You can neither buy nor manually upgrade your daily limit. The only way I know of is requesting more quota through their formulas.